# Entity Framework c#: Bug when AddRange in loop

Tags: c#, database, frameworks, entity, addrange

I have 2 millions of "pb" object instances. I want to add it to my database. Because of memory i splitted list of my objects into a collections of lists and in "for" loop I am trying to add 10'000 of my object instances to database per iteration.

Here is my code

```
 for (int i = 0; i < splittedList.Count; i++)                    
 {                         
    using(MyEntities db = new MyEntities()) //DB context                            
    {                         
    List<pb> outputPBs = splittedList[i];                        
    db.pb.AddRange(outputPBs);
    db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately first iteration add 10'000 instances, but next one add 10'370 instances instead of 10'000. This bug propagate till the last iteration.

I've made a long debug: I add proper list with AddRange, however db.pb.Local contains 10'370 objects after AddRange execution.

This additional 370 objects are instances from the previous iteration.

Could You help me?

Here is a code, which I used to split a list:

```
public static List<List<object>> Split(List<object> source)
{
    return  source
        .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 3)
        .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
        .ToList();
}
```

edit: completed

I solved an issue. Problem was connected with one to many relation. I created tree data structure, and added root in different context than branches and leafs

Comment: Is this happening beyond a certain threshold? With less instances it doesn't do that? Your splittedlist contains 10.000 objects each, right?

Comment: I tried to split a list into packs of 100 instances and it works this way:
1st iteration: 100 elements added, table contains 100 elements
2nd iteration: 200 elements added (100 proper and 100 additional), table contains 300 elements
3rd iteration: 300 elements added (100 proper and 200 additional), table contains 600 elements

Those additional elements in this case are copy of elements from previous insertion.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating a new on every iteration it doesn't make sense how there could be a 'left over' 370 objects from the previous iteration, with regards to the context that is.

Are you completely sure your split is working correctly?

With

```
List<pb> outputPBs = splittedList[i];
```

Are you saying that outputPBs.Count = 10,000 ?

Are the additional 370 objects actually PBs or do any of the PBs contain relationships to other objects that are possibly being added to the object count?

Comment: I've attached to the main point splitting function which I used to split list.

Yes - outputPBs.Count = 10000;
Additional 370 objects are PBs, I think that there are a copy of previously added PBs.

PBs has got a relation with FN (many PBs to one FN). It can be a root cause?

Comment: Before db.pb.AddRange(outputPBs); check the number of PBs in the context, if it's 370 then you are right and they are PBs... check the number of PBs that have a relationship (out of the 10,000 that turn into 10,370)... try using pb.Connection.Open() and pb.Connection.Close() to manage it's connection of the context a little better and prevent any pooling.

Comment: that should be db.Connection.Open() and db.Connection.Close()